# How to force NGINX to use a http proxy when run locally on pc?

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have nginx setup as a reverse proxy. However it does not work as intended at the moment because I need nginx to use a local proxy to reach some services when tun on my PC. I am very unsure how to do that as nginx documentation seems very confusing to me and when attempting to google this question I have met only things regarding reverse proxy configuration which is not what I want to know. Could you please give me any advice or redirect me to some kind of documentation related to this topic?

NOW: app -> locally run nginx reverse proxy -> services

DESIRED: app -> locally run nginx reverse proxy -> proxy -> services

Answer (score 0):

You can use nginx to proxy_pass and socat to listen tcp/unix socket on one side and on another connect to proxy. This solution works for me, but socat bit slow down work.

Run:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:<tcp_port>,fork PROXY:<proxy_ip>:<remote_ip or url>:80,proxyport=<proxy_port>
```

Nginx conf:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<tcp_port>/;
}
```

**For me it was:**

Socat:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:1234,fork PROXY:167.235.34.220:foundation.ton:80,proxyport=8080
```

Nginx:

```
location /validator {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234/;
}
```